# C - How to get a word in a string after a particular word?

Tags: c, c-strings

I need a function or API to get a word after a particular word and store it in a string in C?
For example:

```
char str[] = "This is a sample sentence for demo";
char x[10];
```

Now I need to store the word between `"sample"` and `"for"` (i.e. sentence) in string `x`. How can I do that?

Comment: _I need a function or API to get a word after a particular word and store it in a string in C?_ Please show us the attempted code for the same, then only you'll get better help here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>   // isspace()
#include <string.h>  // strlen(), strstr(), sscanf()
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fprintf()

int main(void)
{
    char const *str = "This is a sample sentence for demo";
    char const *needle = "sample";
    size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
    char const *needle_pos = strstr(str, needle);

    // not found, at end of str or not preceded and followed by whitespace:
    if (!needle_pos || !needle_pos[needle_length] || !isspace((char unsigned)needle_pos[needle_length]) ||
        needle_pos != str && !isspace((char unsigned)needle_pos[-1]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\" couldn't be found. :(\n\n", needle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   

    // extract the word following the word at needle_pos:
    char word[100];
    sscanf(needle_pos + needle_length, "%99s", word);
    printf("Found \"%s\" after \"%s\"\n\n", word, needle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to get a word in a string after a particular word?

Step 1, find the position of `"sample"` in `str`.

```
const char *pos = strstr(str, "sample");
```

Step 2: scan from there looking for the next "word"

```
char x[10];
//                      v-v--------- "sample"
//                          v-v----- Next word
if (pos && sscanf(pos, "%*s %9s", x) == 1) {
  printf("Success <%s>\n", x);
} else {
  printf("Key or following word not found\n", x);
}
```