# How to get the words in a line of a file after a matching word

Tags: c, string, file-io

I'm quite a beginner. I have a file "database.txt" which looks like this

```
[1] Death by chocolate muffins
```

The user inserts a number to search for. I have built the key for searching with the user input and strcat and the matching is working but now I want to store the text after the key e.g. Death by chocolate muffins.

```
    char *p = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp_database) != NULL) {
        p = strtok(line," ");
        while(p != NULL) {
            words[i] = p;
            if(strcmp(words[i], key_search) == 0) {
                printf("Match found!");
                //print text after key
            }
            p = strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I found this answer [C - How to get a word in a string after a particular word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161024/c-how-to-get-a-word-in-a-string-after-a-particular-word), but it is only for printing the next word.

Comment: Why do you say it's only for printing the next word? The answers there put the word in a variable. Once you do that you can do anything you want with it, not just print it.

Comment: Perhaps read from ```database.txt``` after a successfull match until you find a newline, and store it in a buffer?

Comment: After you get first string with strtok and dpace as a separator, you should get yhe remaining line with `'/n'` as a separator.